# Chart JS : Getting issue with draw bar chart

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, chart.js

I am trying to create bar chart with `chart.js`
I tried with 2 methods

1) mention on chart js site it's working ok
    [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxrsj3xb/)

2) also tried this method [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bkr5e5h/), but this was not working return error

> Chart.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 4 of JSFiddle is your problem:

```
 newbardata.lables = [""];
```

you need to fix it to

```
 newbardata.labels = [""];
```

the chart will render properly afterwards.

Here is an updated JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7bkr5e5h/2/

Comment: Thanks for help, both code look same, will you please let me know what mistake I made

Comment: got it spell mistake

Answer (score 1):

it looks like youve misspelt labels.

when you start creating your newbardata object you spell labels as lables and the chart library is looking for a property called labels.